# ASCII Dec to Char in C++

Tags: c++

I want to get every characters of ASCII in normal char. If I only put `char key` only, it would return dec.

My request:

```
char alph = //ascii dec to normal char
```

For example: A in dec is 65
Note: I don't have the characters, but I do have the ASCII codes in dec like 65.

Comment: Well: `char alph = 97;`. Though this is `'a'`, not `'A'` (`65`), and you assume that your environment is based on ASCII, which is not necessarily the case.

Comment: What is a normal char? The value is already a number. It is only a matter of how you print it.

Comment: because I need user input like **65 (A)**, I also need the converted ascii to know what letter they're (user) using

Comment: `WriteLog(toupper('A' <= **alph** && **alph** <= 'Z'));`

Comment: this particular code won't work if i just put `key` instead of `alph` which `char key;` will return `65` is user input is A

Comment: and also `WriteLog` won't do the topupper because it is int.

Comment: **SORRY, i meant I need the normal characters like A, but I don't have it. I only have the user input as ASCII dec**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> because I need user input like **65**

In this case you can do this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int code;
    cout << "Enter a char code:" << endl;
    cin >> code;

    char char_from_code = code;
    cout << char_from_code << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This will ouput:

```
Enter a char code:
65
A
```

Comment: **SORRY, i meant I need the normal characters like A, but I don't have it. I only have the user input as ASCII dec**

Comment: @KhairoulIkhwan the code above is what you really want, did you look at it carefully.

Comment: @KhairoulIkhwan: In this example, the user enters 65 and the programs understands that it means 'A'. As I've said in another comment, note however that this supposes that your environment (OS, compiler, etc.) is based on ASCII.

Comment: @mikedu95 I think do not to explain more, he didn't look at carefully or run your code. After doing that he will see that you code is correct.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have misunderstood the concept.

The numerical value is always there. Whether you print it as the letter or the numerical value depends on how you print.

std::cout will print chars as letters (aka chars) so you'll need to cast it to another integer type to print the value.

```
char c = 'a';
cout << c << endl;             // Prints a
cout << (uint32_t)c << endl;   // Prints 97

cout << endl;

uint32_t i=98;
cout << i << endl;
cout << (char)i << endl;
```

Output:

```
a
97

98
b
```

Comment: well, according to my case, i don't have the character (example: a) but I do have the ascii dec

Comment: @KhairoulIkhwan - you can of cause also do the same starting from integer value - see update

Answer (score 0):

This is the method, very simple and then just need to make your own user interface to get input `dec`

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int dec = 65;
    cout << char(dec);
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need hex/unhex converter. See at boost, or use this bicycle:

```
vector<unsigned char> dec2bin( const string& _hex )
{
    vector<unsigned char> ret;

    if( _hex.size() < 2 )
    {
        return ret;
    }

    for( size_t i = 0; i <= _hex.size() - 2; i += 2 )
    {
        string two = string( _hex.data() + i, 2 );
        stringstream ss( two );
        string ttt = ss.str();
        int tmp;
        ss >> /*hex >>*/ tmp;
        unsigned char c = (unsigned char)tmp;
        ret.insert( ret.end(), c );
     }

     return ret;
 }

 int main()
 {  
     string a = "65";
     unsigned char c = dec2bin( a )[0];
     cout << (char)c << endl;
     return 0;
 }
```